# How to calculate file transfer time for multipart

Tags: ruby, file-upload, rest-client

I am providing a RESTful API, and I want the client to send data as multipart. When client sends data (zip file) to the server, it's taking too much time. Please suggest me how I will calculate (get) file transfer time so that I will implement count down timer.

Comment: The duration of the transfer is the duration of the transfer of the slowest part.

Comment: How will i get time duration?, As sending zip folder.

Comment: @gpalex, no, it is not.  It is the duration of the entirety of the transfer.  This is a function of rate and time.  My car can do 65 miles per hour during part of the trip, and yet, if I drive 15 for the majority of the trip, the duration is increased.

Comment: @vgoff If I understood correctly there are multiparts, so it's parallel transfers. In your example, there would be several cars and the question would be : when does the race end? The race ends when the slowest car passes the finish line.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  So the only thing left to know is how the parts are divided and the rate.  @gpalex thanks.